# Алгоритм составления комплекта товаров из комплектов меньшего размера

Tags: алгоритм

1. Есть некоторое количество комплектов товаров вида {код товара 1, код товара 2, ..., код товара n1}, {код товара 1, код товара 2, ..., код товара n2}, ..., {код товара 1, код товара 2, ..., код товара nk}
   При этом отдельные комплекты могут иметь как совпадающие между собой товары (полностью или частично), так и совершенно различные.
2. Есть заявка на комплект товаров вида {код товара 1, код товара 2, ..., код товара m}
3. Известно, что 0 < n1, n2, …, nk <= m
4. Известно, что все коды товаров из имеющихся комплектов входят в состав заявки, иначе говоря отсутствуют комплекты, содержащие товары, не включенные в заявку.
5. Известно, что коды товаров в комплектах и в зяавке отсортированы по возрастанию.

Необходим алгоритм составления большего комплекта товаров по заявке из имеющихся меньших комплектов товаров, если возможно с минимизацией количества используемых комплектов.

При этом необходимо учитывать, что в итоговом решении каждый товар должен присутствовать только один раз. Сортировка комплектов в решении не важна.

**Пример**:

Имеются комплекты товаров:

```
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {1}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 5}, {3}
```

Есть заявка на комплект товаров:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

В качестве решения принимаются:

```
1.  {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}
2.  {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3}
3.  {1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}
```

Решение

```
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}
```

не принимается, так как товар 1 присутствует 2 раза.

Пока мне на ум приходит только полный перебор вариантов с выбором минимального по количеству комплектов.

Может быть есть менее затратный алгоритм?

Comment: товары в комлектах сортированные? У вас есть гарантия, что существует хотя бы один набор комплектов для ответа? Является ли ответом {1, 2, 3, 4}{3, 4, 5} ?

Comment: 1. товары в комплектах сортированные. 2. нет гарантии, что решение существует. 3. Товары в решении должны присутствовать только один раз, поэтому ответ {1, 2, 3, 4}{3, 4, 5} не подходит. Спасибо за последний вопрос, сейчас добавлю его в условие.

Comment: результат тоже должен быть отсортирован? Например, является ли ответом {1, 3}(2, 5){4} ?

Comment: Сортировка результата не обязательна. Да, такой вариант {1, 3}{2, 5}{4} является решением

Comment: тогда я вижу что то типа графа. Есть точка 0, она соединена со всеми наборами. Также 2 набора соединены, если у них нет общих элементов. Вам надо выполнить поиск в ширину из точки 0 до момента, как все узлы в пути образуют искомый набор.

Comment: Да, такой вариант действительно подходит. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: а для наборов (1,3,4) (2,4)  заявка (1,2,3) валидна?

Comment: Нет, невалидна, так как такая ситуация противоречит условию "4. Известно, что все коды товаров из имеющихся комплектов входят в состав заявки, иначе говоря отсутствуют комплекты, содержащие товары, не включенные в заявку." В данном случае в наборах присутствует товар 4, который отсутствует в заявке

Comment: Это похоже на задачу о покрытии множества с условием неповторяемости. Задача, увы, NP-полная